# How to fill href tag with data from json and when clicked use the selected value in form to post

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

hope all of you have a really nice day.
Im working on a project right now and i cant seem to get this right.
I have the following Json.

```
{
"Error":200,
"Fecha":"6/19/2018",
"Nombreag":"Canchas de Tenis",
"Nombretges":"Reserva de cancha",
"horarios":[
    {
        "horaM":"1000",
        "hora":"10:00AM"
    },
    {
        "horaM":"1030",
        "hora":"10:30AM"
    },
    {
        "horaM":"1100",
        "hora":"11:00AM"
    },
    {
        "horaM":"1130",
        "hora":"11:30AM"
    },
    {
        "horaM":"1200",
        "hora":"12:00PM"
    },
    {
        "horaM":"1230",
        "hora":"12:30PM"
    },
    {
        "horaM":"1300",
        "hora":"01:00PM"
    },
    {
        "horaM":"1330",
        "hora":"01:30PM"
    },
    {
        "horaM":"1400",
        "hora":"02:00PM"
    },
    {
        "horaM":"1430",
        "hora":"02:30PM"
    },
    {
        "horaM":"1500",
        "hora":"03:00PM"
    },
    {
        "horaM":"1530",
        "hora":"03:30PM"
    },
    {
        "horaM":"1600",
        "hora":"04:00PM"
    },
    {
        "horaM":"1630",
        "hora":"04:30P.M."
    },
    {
        "horaM":"1700",
        "hora":"05:00P.M."
    }
]
```

}

And i would like to add a href link based on all the Json inside horarios.
This is for a HTML form to make a POST to my api, i want to display "hora" in the List view and when clicked set the horaM value for using that selection to post.

[image: Like this image.]

I know i have to use Javascript DOM like this but cant get to work the onclick on the href pass that value to the variable and marked it as selected.

I was thinking maybe something like this to get the value.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>
<ul id="loadListview" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" >
  <li><a href="#" id="1200" onclick="myFunction()">12:00PM</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="1230" onclick="myFunction()">12:30PM</a></li>  
  <li><a href="#" id="1300" onclick="myFunction()">1:00PM</a></li>  
  <li><a href="#" id="1330" onclick="myFunction()">1:30PM</a></li>  
</ul>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = this.href;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

But im getting undefined value.

Thanks in advance for all your kind help and i greatly appreciate you taking the time for reading this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to tell `myFunction` which `a` is clicked, you need to pass `this` to the onclick function, so it will look like this `onclick="myFunction(this)"`

```
<ul id="loadListview" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" >
    <li><a href="#THIS_HREF" data-hora="1200" onclick="myFunction(this)">12:00PM</a> </li>
</ul>
<p id="demo">x</p>
```

and then in the function add argument `a`. Also i will recommend using `data-{attribute}` like so

```
<script>
function myFunction(a) {
 var x = a.href; // "a" is the clicked element
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
 console.log(a.dataset.hora) // here is the data-hora attribute
 return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Worked great, i just changed that a.href for a.id cause what i need is the ID.